# How can I get a single element from a json?

Tags: json, angular, angularjs, typescript, database

I am creating a marketplace in angular and I have created the marketplace page which is populated by a remote json created with mockapi. The problem is that in the homepage I want to display a single item (possibly random) from the same json but with *ngFor it displays all the items.

This is my code:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    nfts: any;
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getNfts()
    }

    getNfts() {
        this.http.get('https://63bd1526fa38d30d85d88179.mockapi.io/NFT/v1/metadata').subscribe((data) => {
            this.nfts = data
        })
    }

}

// HTML

            <div class="card cards card-p" *ngFor="let nft of nfts">
                <img src="{{nft.image}}" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="nft-title">{{nft.name}}</h4>
                    <a class="nft-collection mb-3" routerLink="/">NFT collection</a>
                    <p>Price: <span>300</span></p>
                    <button class="button heart text-end"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></button>
                    <a routerLink="/nft-details/:id" class="stretched-link"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I hope someone can help me! Thank you!

Comment: If you only want to show one item, then you could add an additional property `selectedNft` in your component that you assign when the `get()` has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is display a single element (random) from an array then you can use something like "Math.floor(Math.random() * this.nfts.length)" to get a random element from the array and display that array.

so the html will look something like this

```
<div class="card cards card-p">
  <img src="{{nfts[randomIndex].image}}" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="nft-title">{{nfts[randomIndex].name}}</h4>
    <a class="nft-collection mb-3" routerLink="/">NFT collection</a>
    <p>Price: <span>300</span></p>
    <button class="button heart text-end"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></button>
    <a routerLink="/nft-details/:id" class="stretched-link"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    nfts: any;
    randomIndex = 0;
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getNfts()
    }

    getNfts() {
        this.http.get('https://63bd1526fa38d30d85d88179.mockapi.io/NFT/v1/metadata').subscribe((data) => {
            this.nfts = data
            this.randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.nfts.length)
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: And if I want to display like 10 items of the json all random? How can I do?

Comment: you can get 10 random elements with something like this this.nfts.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0,10);

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.map` and iterate the elements that use the same syntax.